# How do I deploy a meteor app to my custom domain?

Tags: meteor

I want to deploy my meteor app to `milf.monster.com`. I have tried several things like hitting `meteor deploy milf.monster.com` but so far no luck. I pointed the record hosts to `ghs.google.com` just like in this tutorial : https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/79/95/web-hosting-tutorial-how-to-setup-hosting-for-a-subdomain but still no luck. How do i do this effectively?

Comment: that article link is currently broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct to use `meteor deploy milf.monster.com`, however in your host records, you should point the url to `origin.meteor.com.`